# emacs path replacement

Tags: linux, bash, debian, emacs

I had a old version of emacs, I removed it and install a new one. For this new install I got a `gz` file, and compiled in my laptop. After a successful installation I got a small situation:

If I type: `emacs-26.3` all works fine, the EMACS version 26.3 runs perfectly.

However if I just type `emacs` I get:

`bash: /usr/bin/emacs: No such file or directory`

I would like to type `emacs` and open emacs-26.3 version.

Please, someone has some suggestion to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: Does it change if you type `hash -d emacs`?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks a lot! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `emacs` is just a symbolic link that is automatically created during install so you can simply add a symbolic link `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/emacs-26.3 /usr/bin/emacs`

NOTE: Those are the correct paths for Arch but you probably want to verify the install location with `which emacs-26.3`

Comment: I tried the suggestion from @steeldriver and worked. Thank you!